# How can I make a vertical column line continue across rows where "multicolumn" has been applied?

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn, arydshln

I am making a table where I would like the dashed vertical column line to continue across rows, regardless of whether `multicolumn` has been applied. Since this column line needs to be dashed, I am using the package `arydshln`. Furthermore, the table is gonna be huge and will cover two pages, which is why I use `longtable` rather than `tabular`.

Second question (less important): Since the formulae in the first two rows have a bigger height than the ones in the bottom two rows, I also would like to use different row heights in the table. I haven't managed to find a good solution for this yet.

See below a simplified version of my table:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.3}
\begin{longtable}{l:l}
\textbf{Amplitude} & \textbf{Amplitude*} \\ \hline
$\displaystyle \frac{i}{p^2 + i\epsilon}$ & 
$\qquad \displaystyle -\frac{i}{p^2 - i\epsilon}$ \\
$\displaystyle \frac{i}{p^2 + i\epsilon}$ & 
$\qquad \displaystyle -\frac{i}{p^2 - i\epsilon}$ \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$something$} \\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$something$} \\
$-ie \gamma^\mu$ & $\qquad ie \gamma^\mu$ \\
$-ie \gamma^\mu$ & $\qquad ie \gamma^\mu$ \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could overlay a dashed line using tikz. You might even consider just stacking a bunch of boxes with a given width and height.;

Comment: Thanks John! I guess that would be my "emergency" solution. Although, this is actually not so bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution without `tikz` could be found setting a fixed width for the columns and using a `\makebox` for the double column text.

Please note that:

1. I've used `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` for the column alignment, but you can use whatever you prefer (idem for the column width `.2\textwidth`, remember to set the `\makebox` width accordingly)
2. load `array` (as well as `longtable`) package before `arydshln`, otherwise you'll get an error
3. you'll get `Overfull \hbox...` but, in this case, it is wanted.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{.2\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{.2\textwidth}}
\newcommand{\mybox}[1]{\makebox[\dimexpr.4\textwidth+\columnsep\relax]{\centering #1}}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.3}
\begin{longtable}{L:R}
\textbf{Amplitude} & \textbf{Amplitude*} \\ \hline
$\displaystyle \frac{i}{p^2 + i\epsilon}$ & 
$\qquad \displaystyle -\frac{i}{p^2 - i\epsilon}$ \\
$\displaystyle \frac{i}{p^2 + i\epsilon}$ & 
$\qquad \displaystyle -\frac{i}{p^2 - i\epsilon}$ \\
\mybox{$something$}& \\
\mybox{$something$}& \\
$-ie \gamma^\mu$ & $\qquad ie \gamma^\mu$ \\
$-ie \gamma^\mu$ & $\qquad ie \gamma^\mu$ \\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]